# Python top 20 names code using classes

Tags: python, class

Alright so I am trying to figure out a way to print the top 20 baby names of a given year. I have over 200 text files with every name given and how many occurrences of that name there are. They are split up by gender here is an example

```
year 1992:

Ashley,F,38451
Jessica,F,38349
Amanda,F,25027
Brittany,F,24974
Sarah,F,24632
Samantha,F,24402
Emily,F,21831
Stephanie,F,19670
Elizabeth,F,19020
Megan,F,17843
...

Michael,M,54373
Christopher,M,42459
Matthew,M,37729
Joshua,M,36207
Andrew,M,30530
Brandon,M,29618
Daniel,M,29138
Tyler,M,28792
James,M,28502
```

I need to find a way to split the top 20 ranked names regardless of gender for any given year  and print them out while prompting for the year. I also can't figure out how to prompt for the year without typing out the entire txt file name with its directory here is what I tried:

```
def main():
    year = input('Enter Year: ')
    for line in open('names/yob',str(year),'.txt'):
        print(line)
```

I don't see why this doesn't work. also I think I need to make a class something like this and a way of making an entry:

```
class entry():
    __slots__ = ('gender', 'rank')

def mkEntry(...):
    ...
```

It should have an output something like this

```
Enter Year: 1992
1. Josh (M): 52013
2. Jessica (F): 51001
3. Michael (M): 48923

...


20. Sarah (F): 34013
```

I just don't understand how to split up the files into the highest rank regardless of gender and print out the top 20. I'm guessing you use lists but how could I go about doing this? All help would be much appreciated.

EDIT:

Alright I have developed code but am getting the error that a list can't have the attribute of rank in the line if mlst.rank > flst.rank: could you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/fa367ff6955b10ae6e11

Comment: Why do you want to use a class for this?

Comment: Just for clarity, you are using Python 3?

Comment: Do the files always start with `year YYYY:` and a blank line or is that not part of the file?

Comment: they always start with a year and yes this is python 3

Comment: A class would help me further my understanding of the language

Comment: Building a class that doesn't do anything useful isn't going to further your understanding. Try another project where there's some data type that has methods, not just a couple of values.

Answer (score 3):

You need to concatenate the strings when opening the file, or use string formatting; `open()` does not work like `print()`, it won't guess what arguments should be concatenated:

```
for line in open('names/yob{}.txt'.format(year)):
```

Next, you have CSV files, so use the `csv` module to read them:

```
import csv

with open('names/yob{}.txt'.format(year), 'rU') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=',')
```

Next I'd use a [`collections.Counter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to track name counts:

```
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter()

for row in reader:
    name, sex, count = row
    counts[name, sex] += int(count)
```

Now you have a per-name-and-sex count, and can ask for the top 20:

```
for (name, sex), count in counts.most_common(20):
    print('{} ({}): {}'.format(name, sex, count))
```

Comment: You'll also need to skip over the "Year:" header line and the blank line(s), which hopefully the OP can figure out himself, and then this is all you need. However, I don't think you actually need a Counter here. It looks like each name occurs exactly once, so a plain old dict would be fine.

Comment: Actually, scrap the dict; just pass the reader to heapq,nlargest and you're done.

Comment: Is there a way to incorporate a class and not using the csv module?

Comment: Sure, but that'd be artificial and non-optimal. There are several others solving the same homework questions here on Stack Overflow today; look through the recent list of Python questions and see what they are doing.

Comment: Alright I made an edit and can't seem to figure out why I'm getting an error.

Answer (score 1):

Martijn's answer shows how to read in the data. But, assuming each name and sex only occurs once per file, you don't need a Counter. You can just use heapq.nlargest. This makes it a one-liner instead of a three-liner, and it means you only need enough memory to store 20 names at a time instead of all of the names in the file.

I'll edit this with real tested code when I'm not on a phone, but something like this:

```
# above here the same as Martijn's code up to reader
top20 = heapq.nlargest(reader, operator.itemgetter(2))
for name, sex, count in top20:
    # same print line as in Martijn's code
```